# How to send window.alert message from node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, alert

I want to send window alerts from my node backend to my frontend which is made in ejs.

Here I want to send a window alert if the entered username already exists.

```
User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
            .then(result => {
                if (result) {
                    console.log('Username already taken!')  //this thing I want to show to user via an alert
                    res.render('register')
                } else {
                    user.save()
                        .then(res.redirect('login'))
                        .catch(err => console.log(err))
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

The alert() method in JS could be used as well inside the node code if I'm not mistaken.

```
if (result) {
    alert('Username already taken!') 
    res.render('register')
```

Alternative: the alert npm package, pretty easy to use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/alert

Answer (score 0):

There is an `npm` module for popups known as `popups`. You have to install it using the command `npm install popups`. Then use below code :

```
var popup = require('popups');

popup.alert({
    content: 'Hello!'
})
```

For more information here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/popups